# Copy all the files from a folder in to another by comparing files in it

Tags: maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

How we can copy all the files from one folder into to another by comparing all the files in that folder, if files content changed then copy the file into another project location otherwise not.

Any suggestion that which plugin that I should try with?

I am trying using `maven-antrun-plugin` (version 1.7) but no success yet.

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <target name="main">
                        <ant antfile="/build.xml" target="main" />
                     </target>
                </configuration>
                    <goals>
                         <goal>run</goal>
                     </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
      <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
     <version>1.0b3</version>
 </dependency>

</plugin>
```

Comment: You have a basic mistake. `Apache Maven AntRun Plugin` don't suite with your purpose. Read reference document: **This plugin provides the ability to run Ant tasks from within Maven. You can even embed your Ant scripts in the POM!** https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/

Comment: Any suggestion to use another plugin ?

Comment: I don't know why you work on 2 projects at same time. General speaking, **Build tool** work with **only one project** at a time.

Comment: Even in the same project how can we do it?

Comment: I and my fellows often don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do by using maven-antrun-plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target name="build">
                                <ant antfile="build.xml"
                                    target="build" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0b3</version>
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                <groupId>ant</groupId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="prospector" basedir="/" default="main">
<target name="main" depends="etc"/>

<target name="etc">

        <for param="file">
            <path>
                <fileset
                    dir="etc"
                    includes="**/**" />
            </path>
            <sequential>
                <var name="name" unset="true" />
                <basename file="@{file}" property="name" />
                <if>
                    <filesmatch file1="@{file}" file2="etc/${name}" /> 
                    <then>
                        <echo message="There is no change in ${name}" />
                    </then>
                    <else>
                        <echo message="There are some changes in ${name}" />
                        <copy
                            file="@{file}"
                            tofile="etc/${name}" overwrite="true"/> 
                    </else>
                </if>


            </sequential>
        </for>
    </target>
```